# Angular 2 - Using pipe in (click) event

Tags: events, angular, parameters, pipe

My question is probably simple but just can't find the way to use pipe within an event like (click) for example. Something like this:

```xml
<button (click)="quizAnswers(answer?.texte | translate | async)"></button>
```

I always get an error. I tried to wrap it with `()` or `{}` or `[]`...
There are some workaround like putting the content in an attribute and then get it on the event with `this.attribute` but I'm sure there is a proper way !

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression`

Comment: Looking for the same solution. What is the attribute workaround and could you share it?

Answer (score 7):

A workaround would be to call your pipes in the click handler function instead:

```typescript
function quizAnswers(answer)
{
    let translatePipe= new TranslatePipe();
    ...
    return translatePipe.transform(answer?.texte);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeap I'm using this workaround already actually. I just wanted to know how to do it within the template, but thanks anyway

Comment: Thank you, It's a littly hacky for definently useful!

Answer (score 6):

I just got through this same issue. Action expressions can't contain the `async` pipe. However, you can use a hidden `<input>` element to hold the latest value of the promise/observable stream, and then access that value anywhere.

```xml
  <input #dummy style="{display: none}" type="text" value="{{ myAsyncSource | async }}">
  <a (click)="myFunction(dummy.value)">{{ dummy.value }}</a>
```

For your case of `<button>` there's actually a one-line solution that eliminates the need for the dummy `<input>`, posted [in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730811/how-to-pass-a-value-inside-an-observable-to-click-handler-in-angular2):

```xml
 <button type="button" #item value="{{i$ | async}}"  (click)="buttonClicked(item.value)">BUTTON</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to simulate assignment using `*ngIf`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ text: answer$ | async } as data"> // is important to save it in an object, so it's always truthy
  <button (click)="quizAnswers(data.text)"></button>
</ng-container>
```

Or you can use a library if you prefer it with `*ngLet`: https://github.com/nigrosimone/ng-let