# Angular - Calling a pipe within click event

Tags: html, angular, typescript, events, pipe

I am having problems trying to find the best way to use a pipe within a (click) event. I am receiving a "cannot have a pipe in an action expression" error. I would like to be able to trigger the pipe when user clicks the button. The goal with this program is when the user clicks the "CM" button, the values in the length column with convert to centimeters. Any help on solving this error or finding a better solution would be greatly appreciated.

Table

```
                       If user selects centimeters

in cm                         in cm
--------------------          ---------------        
User |Item  | Length        User | Item  | Length 
--------------- ---->      ---------------
User1|Item1 | 12 cm         User1| Item1 | 12 cm
User2|Item2 | 2 in          User2| Item2 | 5.08 cm
```

Pipe

```
@Pipe({name:convertToCmPipe})
export class ConvertToCmPipe implements PipeTransform {
 constructor(public log:LoggingService){}
 transform(value:number,newVal: string): any {
   return newVal === undefined ? value : value * 2.54;

   }
}
```

Typescript

```
onBtnSelect(x: number)
{
  return this.convertToCmPipe.transform(x,x);
}
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="onBtnSelect(lengthVal | convertToCmPipe: 'length')"
title="cm"> CM </button>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678101/angular-2-using-pipe-in-click-event) can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In html:

```
<button (click)="onBtnSelect()"> change </button>
{{lengthVal | (isClicked? (convertToCmPipe: 'length') : '')}}
```

In ts:

```
isClicked = false;
onBtnSelect() {
  this.isClicked = !this.isClicked;
}
```

Not sure what will work, give the feedback.